# mutate list of dataframes with another list

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

I've got a list of 17 dataframes and a list of 17 dates. They are ordered and correspond to each other. In other words, `list_of_dfs[[1]]` corresponds to `dates[[1]]` and so forth. The list of dates, below, are date objects using `lubridate::ymd`.

```
> dates
[1] "2004-10-10" "2005-10-10" "2006-10-10" "2007-10-10" "2008-10-10" "2009-10-10" "2010-10-10" "2011-10-10" "2012-10-10" "2013-10-10" "2014-10-10" "2015-10-10" "2016-10-10" "2017-10-10"
[15] "2018-10-10" "2019-10-10" "2020-10-10"
```

I would like to mutate a subset of variables in each dataframe such that I am subtracting the subset from the corresponding object in `dates`. For example, I could do the following for the first item.

```
list_of_dfs[[1]] <- list_of_dfs[[1]] %>% `
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains('string')),
            .funs = funs(dates[[1]] - .)
```

Is there a way that I incorporate the above into a `map` or `lapply` like command that will allow me to iterate through `dates`?

My closet approximation would be something like

```
list_of_dfs <- list_of_dfs %>%
      map(., function(x) mutate_at(x,
                               .vars = vars(contains('string')),
                               .funs =  funs(dates - .)))
```

which can't take a list object in `.funs` as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` as we are doing the subtraction from corresponding elements of 'dates' `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list_of_dfs2 <- map2(list_of_dfs, dates, ~ {date <- .y
                    .x   %>%
                          mutate_at(vars(contains('string')), ~ date - as.Date(.))})
```

In the devel version of `dplyr`, `across` can be used along with `mutate`

```
list_of_dfs2 <- map2(list_of_dfs, dates, ~ { date <- .y
                 .x %>%
                    mutate(across(contains('string'), ~ date - as.Date(.x)))
   })
```

#### data

```
list_of_dfs <- list(data.frame(string1 = Sys.Date() -   1:6, string2 = Sys.Date()), 
          data.frame(string1 = Sys.Date() -   1:6, string2 = Sys.Date()))
dates <- Sys.Date() + 1:2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion! Should the last bit read `~ .y - .` ? I want to make sure I understand what is going on

Comment: This returns the following error which might be somewhat to untangle without direct access to the data `Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x The subscript has the wrong type `formula`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.` Both the data frames columns of interest and the list of dates are date-type

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be very close! I do not get this error message anymore which is great. however, if I have `date[[1]]` and I am subtracting `NA` from that date, I get `NA` as the result. I would want the `date` to remain unchanged, no? I guess that I could have some work around that switches `NA` to `0` but this feels inefficient.

Comment: also need `=` to be `-` in order for it to run but yes it works

Comment: Sorry, when I changed, a typo

Comment: Sure, any clue what I can do on the NA problem described?

Comment: @JackReimer  I tried the code on an example created (updated  with the example),  it seems to be working for me.  Can you check whether the 'string' columns are `Date` class

Comment: @JackReimer if it is character, then `mutate_at(vars(contains('string')), ~ date - as.Date(.))}`

Comment: Thanks, yes all of the date variables involved are date class. there must be some incompatibility specific to the data, thank you for spelling out the mutate call with `as.Date`